# SMB authentication via domain accounts from non-domain machine

Tags: security, authentication, kerberos

I would like to ask if somebody could explain me how exactly user/account is authenticated in following scenario:

- SMB File Server is part of the domain
- access to the File server is granted via domain accounts
- Client is outside of the domain and firewalled only to see the File Server.
- Client is going to use domain credentials to authenticate to the File Server.

My question is how the Kerberos tickets are created if Client is not having visibility to KDC/Domain Controllers? is it going to be the File Server acting as a client for the KDC or relay the request if yes how the credentials are stored on the File Server? Or will be other authentication method used in this case e.g. NTLM?

Thanks!

Tomas

Comment: Unless client and server implement https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zhu-ws-kerb-03 they will resort to NTLM.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244137/can-a-kerberos-application-server-offer-to-proxy-connections-to-the-kdc